# Are Random Forests limited for forecasting/projection purposes

Tags: forecasting, random-forest

Today a coworker came asking me if we could train a model that will predict some land prices and then use said model to predict on hypothetical data.

Let's say, I have a `Period` feature that goes from 1 to 100, where 1 is the first day of data and 1000 is the last day of data. Then, say the last data point for `district A` was on day 750. If I then ask my model (assuming it's a Random Forest) to predict a price for `district A` on day 1000, will it be able to have into consideration that prices will be constantly rising, even though there was no training data for that district on that range of days? What if I ask it to predict a price for day 1200? If the day is out of the training range, it won't be able to project how much the price would have risen, right?

Any help to know if I'm on the right way would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Yes it will, but the prediction won't be any different than if the input (day, in this case) were the maximum one observed in the training data.

Comment: That's what I thought. So which kind of models might I use to predict out of training range? Ideally more powerful than Logistic Regression

Comment: I don't see why the Logistic Regression was mentioned, since prices are more of float nature. Nonetheless, I would try time-series approaches, starting from seasonal decomposition, then AR, and (S)ARIMA, which allow longer period forecasts.

Comment: My bad, I'm working on another classification problem and my brain mixed both. Let's say Linear Regression, that I'm positive that because of the nature of coefficients can project and forecast to values outside the training sample ranges. I'll try with time series approaches, too. Do LSTM Neural Networks work for forecasting purposes?